# Get todays midnight Timestamp

Tags: php, time

So I am having a little trouble getting today's midnight date using the midnight time using the `time()` function.
It is a little confusing for me when I explain to my peers on the timestamp I want. What I need is, if today is wed-06-Aug-2014 at 9:00pm , then I want the time at wed-06-Aug-2014 00:00.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Just use relative date and time formats:

```
echo date('D-d-M-Y H:i', strtotime('midnight'));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/176269)